# Constructor with argument :Missing return int value

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have class which contains many properties:

```
public class Report
{
    public int reportId { get; set; }
    public string sentDate { get; set; }
    public string photoName { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string patientName { get; set; }
    public string doctorName { get; set; }
    public string sex { get; set; }
    public int isPregnant { get; set; }
    public float weight { get; set; }
    public float height { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string information { get; set; }
    public string response { get; set; }
```

then I implement one constructor with argmuents :

```
public Report(int id, string photoName, string sentDate, string state,string response)
{
    this.reportId = id;
    this.photoName = photoName;
    this.sentDate = sentDate;
    this.state = state;
    this.response = response;
}
```

finally I implement method which calls this constructor :

```
 public static List<Report> GetListReportByEmail(string email)
{      
    DataTable dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(
        new SqlConnection(Tls.ConnStr), 
        "spReportGetByEmail", 
        email).Tables[0];
    List<Report> tempItems = new List<Report>();
    if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
    {

        foreach (DataRow rw in dt.Rows)
        {
            tempItems.Add(
                new Report(
                    int.Parse(rw["ReportId"].ToString()), 
                    Tls.GetBasicUrl() + "/Zdnn000kjUpload/__zd__MedicalConsultation/" 
                        + rw["PhotoName"].ToString(), 
                    DateTime.Parse(rw["SentDate"].ToString()).ToString("dd/M/yyyy"), 
                    rw["State"].ToString(), 
                    rw["Response"].ToString()));
        }
        return tempItems;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

but when I check the return, in addition of the properties mentionned in the constructor I found all properties which its type is `int` or `float`  with the value 0.

I need this methods for a web services. when I test this web serives I found properties mentionned in the constructor ,but also `int` and `float` which are not populated:

```
<Report>
<reportId>4</reportId>
<sentDate>21/6/2014</sentDate>
<photoName>
http://localhost:2055/Zdnn000kjUpload/__zd__MedicalConsultation/
</photoName>
<state/>
<isPregnant>0</isPregnant>
<weight>0</weight>
<height>0</height>
<age>0</age>

<response/>
</Report>
```

Knowing that the stored procedure is ok.

So can any one help me to transmit only variables mentionned in the constructor : I don't need `age`,`height`,`weight`,`isPregnant` to be transmitted

Thanks.

Comment: Well your constructor only sets a few of the properties - what do you expect to populate the rest?

Comment: What you see is expected. Other properties are not updated so they are 0. What exactly is the question?

Comment: with this method I need just to populate these properties, the other will not be populated , but I found it in the return of this methods.

Comment: I think that @Himitcho wants the unpopulated properties to _not_ be included in the xml.  I'm thinking that in order to accomplish that, you might need to use Nullable<T> as the property types.  For example `public float? weight { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor only assigns the following:

```
this.reportId = id;
this.photoName = photoName;
this.sentDate = sentDate;
this.state = state;
this.response = response;
```

Why would you expect the other properties (`isPregnant`, `weight`, `height`, `age`, etc.) to be populated as well? You are not assigning those properties value at any point.

Comment: i need to transmit these values to web service, so i need only variables mentionned in the constructor

Comment: But wen I test the web services I found  <Report>
<reportId>4</reportId>
<sentDate>21/6/2014</sentDate>
<photoName>
http://localhost:2055/Zdnn000kjUpload/__zd__MedicalConsultation/
</photoName>
<state/>
<isPregnant>0</isPregnant>
<weight>0</weight>
<height>0</height>
<age>0</age>
<response/>
</Report>